# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError even if the class is in the jar

Tags: jar, classnotfoundexception, jnlp

I've seen several questions & solutions similar to my problem but none of them has been effective to me. The version of java I'm using for building my jnlp is the same i use when i launch it. java compliance level is correct & of course, the class that should be missing in my jar is present though.

Is there another setting I should check ? Am I missing something else ?

Comment: and is your JAR in the classpath?

Comment: Yes, it is in the classpath